# mongodb aggregate, group and sort

Tags: mongodb

I need help with a query in mongo where I want to fetch the `posts` tags where post `status: 'accepted`, group the tags and order them by occurrences.

```
db.collection('Posts').aggregate([{
        $project: {
                tags: 1
        }
}, {
        $unwind: "$tags"
}, {
        $group: {
                _id: {
                        tag: "$tags"
                },
                count: {
                        $sum: 1
                }
        }
}], function (error, result) {
        // do stuff
});
```

This works but they do not order by that `count` field and I don't know how to select only posts that have status `accepted`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter posts by status, you can use [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator. For ordering by count you should use [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) operator.

Updated version of the query should be like :

```
db.collection('Posts').aggregate([
{$match : {status : "accepted"}},
{$project: {tags: 1}}, 
{$unwind: "$tags"}, 
{$group: {_id: {tag: "$tags"},count: {$sum: 1}}},
{$sort : {count : 1}}], 
function (error, result) {
        // do stuff
});
```